# How create wrapper for callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I use ajaxSubmit.

```
form.ajaxSubmit(successCallback);
```

I need create wrapper for successCallback.

How to do this?

I tried

```
form.ajaxSubmit(wrapperCallBack(successCallback));

var wrapperCallBack = function (successCallback) {
        debugger;
        changeState(false);
        successCallback(this);
    };
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: @gdoron: Thanks. I have to say, whoever downvoted your answer was being *really* harsh. I didn't see anything wrong with it (and was reaching to upvote when it disappeared), perfectly valid answer if Denis needed to do it as a one-off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're pretty close:

```
form.ajaxSubmit(wrapperCallBack(successCallback));

var wrapperCallBack = function (successCallback) {
    return function() {
        changeState(false);
        return successCallback(this);
    };
};
```

Or as I would prefer to write it:

```
form.ajaxSubmit(wrapperCallBack(successCallback));

function wrapperCallBack(successCallback) {
    return function() {
        changeState(false);
        return successCallback(this);
    };
}
```

There, `wrapperCallback` creates a function to wrap around its argument (the `successCallback` argument) and returns that function.

Both of those assume you're going to use `wrapperCallBack` to create wrappers more than once. If you only need a one-off, then you can just use an inline anonymous function:

```
form.ajaxSubmit(function() {
    changeState(false);
    return successCallback(this);
});
```